# Bigquery getting "Response too large Error" when using NTILE function with public example dataset on wikipedia

Tags: google-bigquery

Basically I am testing the NTILE function to divide the total word count of wikipedia table into 100 buckets. I am getting the "response too large error" using the web console. So I tried the bq CLI tool with both --destination_table and --allow_large_results options with no luck.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT id, num_characters, NTILE(100) OVER (ORDER BY num_characters) percentile
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]
```

How can I retrieve the results correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigQuery's secret for astonishing performance: Distributing the workload. Whenever you issue a query, a big number of computers start reading all the data in parallel, processing it, and passing it to other computers in the chain.

However, there are operations that are very hard to parallelize - typically functions that run after everything else has been done. Those operations are not being distributed, but constrained to all the data that will fit in one computer. ORDER BY and OVER() are some of these functions - as eventually a single machine needs to sort the whole result set out.

The good news is we have alternatives. QUANTILES is able to go through all the data, while computing approximate results:

```
SELECT QUANTILES(num_characters, 100)
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]

Query complete (1.7s elapsed, 2.34 GB processed)
```

Or running the same OVER (ORDER BY) than in the original question, but over a sample of the data:

```
SELECT id, num_characters, NTILE(100) OVER (ORDER BY num_characters) percentile 
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]
WHERE id % 10 = 0;

Query complete (258.7s elapsed, 4.68 GB processed)
```

You'll see that both produce similar results (one by approximation, the other one by sampling) - but one is much faster.

Comment: Thanks @Fh for the answer. Ultimately I am trying to find all the IDs of the wikipedia articles with char count in 75, 80 and 85 percentiles. QUANTILES function returns me the quantile limits, how can I retrieve the IDs?

Comment: give me a new question so I can paste a lengthy answer :)

Comment: Thanks @Fh, here is the question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060430/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-ids-of-rows-by-percentile-for-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UDF function to get nTiles of all data without memory saturation and without having to sample, though it may be less performant.

I employed this method to calculate the percentile a value fell within, just like the built in `NTILE` function. The built in function would run out of memory during the `ORDER BY` operation, when applied to a massive number of rows.

The user defined function takes an **quantiles array** (in this case generated using `APPROX_QUANTILES`) and a **value** and returns which ntile the value is in.

```
-- Define UDF
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION getNTile(quantiles ARRAY<INT64>, val INT64)
  RETURNS INT64
  LANGUAGE js AS """
    var ntile = 0;

    while(parseInt(val, 10) > parseInt(quantiles[ntile], 10) && ntile < quantiles.length) {
      ntile+=1;
    }

    return ntile;
  """;

-- Calculate an array of approximate quantiles, in this case percentiles
WITH master AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    num_characters
  FROM
    `publicdata.samples.wikipedia`
),
quantiles AS (
  SELECT
    APPROX_QUANTILES(num_characters, 99) AS approx
  FROM
    master
)

-- Use UDF with approx quantile array to find nTile
SELECT
  id,
  num_characters,
  getNTile(quantiles.approx, num_characters) AS percentile
FROM
  master,
  quantiles
```

The JS code in the UDF is forcing the values to integers with `parseInt`. It may be a BigQuery bug, but for some reason the values were coming through as strings otherwise, oddly.

Hope this helps someone.